# Two sets of matrix conditions. Are they equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, classical-mechanics, canonical-transformation

I have reasons to believe that for any four square matrices $A, B, C, D \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, and $\lambda \neq 0$, the following is true:
\begin{equation}
\left.\
\begin{aligned}
A^TD-C^TB &=\lambda I_n
\\ A^TC &=C^TA\\
B^TD&=D^TB
\end{aligned} \right\}
\quad \iff \quad
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
AD^T-BC^T &=\lambda I_n
\\ AB^T &=BA^T\\
CD^T&=DC^T
\end{aligned} \right.\
\end{equation}

I have tried to tackle a proof or find a counterexample, but I haven't been able to do either. I would appreciate any indications or help. Thank you in advance :)

For context, both conditions have appeared when I tried to study whether the following linear transformation:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
Q&=Aq+Bp\\
P&=Cq+Dp
\end{aligned} \right.\
\end{equation}
where $p,q,Q,P \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are supposed to represent old and new coordinates and momenta, respectively, is canonical in the sense of classical mechanics. Specifically, I obtained the first set of conditions after forcing $\sum_{k}(\lambda p_k dq_k-P_k dQ_k)$ to be an exact differential, while the second one appears if one sets $[Q_i,Q_j]=[P_i,P_j]=0, [Q_i,P_j]=\lambda\delta_{ij}$ for the Poisson brackets of the new coordinates. I have studied that both these conditions characterize a canonical transformation, hence the question.

Comment: The two sets of equations simply mean $\pmatrix{A^T&C^T\\ B^T&D^T}\pmatrix{D&-C\\ -B&A}=\lambda I_{2n}$ and
$\pmatrix{D&-C\\ -B&A}\pmatrix{A^T&C^T\\ B^T&D^T}=\lambda I_{2n}$ respectively. They are equivalent because for any pair of linear operators $X$ and $Y$ on a finite-dimensional vector space, [$XY=I$ if and only if $YX=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852).

Comment: @user1551 Cool! So either condition can be expressed as $\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\C & D\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\lambda^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}D & -C \\-B & A\end{pmatrix}^T$, which is really the inverse rule for a $2 \times 2$ matrix,  much more beautiful than what I had. Thank you so much :))